# C++ Identifier not found in abstract class

Tags: c++

I'm having a strange problem that I can't seem to find an answer for, and figured I might as well ask.

I have an abstract class that does collision checking that has an "update" function, and "updateX" and "updateY" functions.

```
class MapCollidable {
public:
    MapCollidable(){}
    ~MapCollidable(){}

    void update(const units::Coordinate2D origin, const Rectangle& boundingBox, 
                 Rectangle& collider, units::Coordinate delta, Level* level, 
                 Direction direction, bool moveAlongSlopes=false);

    void updateX(const Rectangle& destRect, const Rectangle& boundingBox,
                 units::Coordinate delta_x, Level* level, bool moveAlongSlopes=false);
    void updateY(const Rectangle& destRect, const Rectangle& boundingBox, 
                 units::Coordinate delta_y, Level* level, bool moveAlongSlopes=false);


    virtual void onCollision(const CollisionTile::CollisionInfo& collisionInfo) = 0;
    virtual void onDelta(const CollisionTile::CollisionInfo& collisionInfo) = 0;
};
```

Before I would simply have the child call the update function to do collision checking, but recently decided I would like to add the updateX and updateY functions. The child now calls updateX and updateY, which call update. However when I try to call update inside of updateX or updateY, I get a "Identifier 'update' is undefined" error.

```
void updateX(const Rectangle& destRect, const Rectangle& boundingBox,
             units::Coordinate delta_x, Level* level, bool moveAlongSlopes=false) {

      // Get some things ready to call update...
    const units::Coordinate2D origin = units::Coordinate2D(destRect.getLeft(), destRect.getTop());
    Direction direction = delta_x < 0 ? LEFT : RIGHT;
    Rectangle collider ( boundingBox.getLeft() + destRect.getLeft() + delta_x,
        boundingBox.getTop() + destRect.getTop(),
        direction == LEFT ? ( boundingBox.getWidth() / 2 ) - delta_x : (boundingBox.getWidth() / 2) + delta_x,
        boundingBox.getHeight() );


    // Trying to call update here gives the error.
    update(origin, boundingBox, collider, delta_x, level, direction, moveAlongSlopes);
}
```

I've picked through it several times, and I'm not finding anything silly I've done, so why can update not be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining your function as if it was a global one:

```
void updateX(const Rectangle& destRect, const Rectangle& boundingBox,
             units::Coordinate delta_x, Level* level, bool moveAlongSlopes=false) {
  //...
}
```

Change it to:

```
void MapCollidable::updateX(const Rectangle& destRect, const Rectangle& boundingBox,
             units::Coordinate delta_x, Level* level, bool moveAlongSlopes=false) {
  //...
}
```

Call to `update` is signaled as an error, because there is no such function in global scope.

By the way, that's why I **always** reference any member function/variable using **this**.

If you wrote this:

```
void updateX(const Rectangle& destRect, const Rectangle& boundingBox,
                 units::Coordinate delta_x, Level* level, bool moveAlongSlopes=false) {
  //...
  this->update(...);
}
```

You would immediately got following error:

> Error: 'this' only allowed in non-static member functions.

And you would know what is causing this error. Without **this**, many simple errors can be easily omitted.

Comment: Oh god, thank you. I was staring at it for over half an hour and was completely missing that. :)

Comment: Nice tip with the `this->...`

Comment: One more interesting thing about `this`: let's assume you have template class A and template class B, that inherits from A. Inside member functions of B, any member derived from A should be explicitly referenced via `this`. Otherwise, you will get following error (taken from GCC 4.9) `there are no arguments to ‘X’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘X’ must be available`, where `X` is name of some member function/variable. What is interesting, it's that VC++ accepts such code. So, by avoiding `this`es, you can very easily create a highly unportable code.